# How can I manage Google Charts Data Properties properly?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to configure the porperties for my DataTable in js for Google Charts.  I am already configuring this, and it is working but it broke on me a few times the past month and I had to update my method call.

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
```

The first way I used to do this is with the code below which worked until recently (I tested it it yesterday, but haven't looked at it for a couple weeks before):

```
// Check if column title includes Projection.
          if(**data.Sf[i]**["label"].indexOf('Projection') > -1 )
          { 
              //Do Action 
          }
          else
          {
                //Do else action
          }
```

Once the above code broke, I moved on to change the **data.Sf to data.pg** with no other code changes. This fixed the problem.  My concern is that this way of going about things can possibly break again, and I am wondering if there is safer or more consistent way to go about looking at the title for each column in the data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several *helper* [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods)

you shouldn't need to access the objects directly

to get the column label, use...

`dataTable.getColumnLabel(colIndex)`